# how to use IComparable<T> to compare 2 List

Tags: c#, .net

Eg:

```
var ExistingGroup = new List<Person>
{
new Person(1,"Rahul","Sharma"),
new Person(2,"Deepak","Jha"),
new Person(3,"Raj","Mishra"),
}

 var NewGroup = new List<Person>
{
new Person(4,"Jay","Mohan"),
new Person(2,"Dileep","Kumar"),
new Person(5,"Mohan","Lal"),
}
```

Output:

```
1 Removed
4 Added
2 Changed
3 Removed
5 Added
```

How to get this output with `IComparable<T>`?

Answer (score 0):

Implementing IComparable won't help you, because it is meant to enable ordering, it is not meant for change tracking.
You will have write a method that takes two lists and:

1. iterate over the first list while searching each occuring "person number" in the other list -> gives you removed items
2. check persons that appear in both lists for differences -> gives you changed items
3. repeat the other way around -> gives you added  items

You can do so using LINQ.